# need help on how to Import phone number into salesforce using data loader

Tags: data-loader, data

I'm trying to insert phone number using data loader as (XXX)-XXX-XXX format, but upon insert into sales force the number is displaying as XXXXXXXXX format.What i need to do to display phone number as (XXX)-XXX-XXX format.

Thanks

Comment: What's your locale?

Comment: Is this happening with only one specific object's records and page layouts or all of them?